# PHP Redirect to Anchor Link on Another Page When Passing Radio Button Value

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect, anchor

I am attempting to pass a form value to a textbox on another page with php. Specifically, I want to link to the textbox on the other page when the form button on page1 is submitted.

**Page1:**

```
 echo '<td><input type="radio" name="myId" value= " ' . $myId . ' "></td>';

 echo '<input name="mybutton" type="submit" value="Submit">';
```

**Page2**

```
if (isset($_POST['myId'])) {   
header('Location: http://localhost/dirc/mypage.php#link');
$id = trim($_POST['myId']); 
}//if no id passed
else {
$id = "";
}
```

Then on Page2 where the anchor is:

```
//if button clicked on Page1, redirect to here on Page2 and display the value in the textbox:

<a name="link">
<input type="textbox" value="<?php echo $myId;?>">
```

Give the above, if I click mybutton, the redirect to the anchor on the other page works, however the value of the radio button does not get passed!  If I comment out....

```
//header('Location: http://localhost/dirc/mypage.php#link');
```

The myId gets passed but the redirect to the anchor doesn't work.

On Page1 I have also tried checking if mybutton and myId isset:

```
if (isset($_POST['myId']) && ($_POST['mybutton'))
```

But this doesn't make any difference.

There is nothing wrong with myId getting passed to Page2 but the minute I add the header location redirect, this stops the data getting passed?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Where are you defining $myId in your code?

Comment: myId is getting pulled from a Mysql query: $myId = $row['myid'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to :

```
header('Location: http://localhost/dirc/mypage.php?myId='.$_POST['myId']);
```

If you want to access it use

```
<input type="textbox" value="<?php echo $_GET['myId'];?>">
```

---Edited---

```
 header('Location: http://localhost/dirc/mypage.php?myId='.$_POST['myId'].'#'.$_POST['myId']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This posts the data ok but the re-direct to the textbox doesn't work

Comment: With your change, the data is successfully getting passed to the textbox but the redirect still does not work. Here is an example of what is getting passed in the query string: http://localhost/dirc/mypage.php?myId=%2029563%20# 29563.  Trimming the whitespace makes no difference

Comment: You have been very helpful raveenanigam.  Thank you very much.